# Check group add remove permissions for Active Directory service account

Tags: active-directory, active-directory-group

We need to now how we can check whether an account in AD has permissions to add/remove membership on AD group. AD team will be giving our service account permissions for 1000 groups at one time and we want to know a way to check quickly if we really do have permissions before confirming. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Some info here that may help: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6477.how-to-view-or-delete-active-directory-delegated-permissions.aspx - I have used AD ACL Scanner to check permissions before, but not in the context that you require, although it may work for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer except for the fact that when they give you permission you can test adding and removing a test user to a group. But this will all depend on the fact if the groups have all the standard default permissions when created, also the method that the AD team will give you access. Adding you to a built in group that has permission to edit the AD group, or if they are going to create a new group and add that to the AD groups. Sorry to be vague but a lot of variable here.